# Getting the attributes of the last modified file in a directory written in a file

Tags: batch-file, last-modified, file-attributes

I am in the need of a batch script that checks a drive (D:) for the 'last modified' attribute of *.czi files (Carl Zeiss image files) and append the data to a file on another drive. I have tried solutions with the following line:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%*.czi /A:-D /O:-D /T:W /B') DO COPY "%%I" > %target%
```

that does give me the last file, but it copies the entire file which is not that smart since they can be big. As a biologist I will spare you for my desperate attempts that did not work (spent 4-5 hours). I figure this can be done dead easily, that is if you know how... Any good suggestions? Any reply will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define what you mean by attributes, preferably by appending that information to your question.

Comment: also what is the "data" you want to append to the target file? The content of the *.czi file or the 'last modified' attribute?

Comment: Since you are executing a `dir /o-d`, your command should copy the very first-modified file to `target` by copying each in turn starting with the **last**. You would need to use `>>` in place of `>` to append the data. The file "%%I" will be the filename found, but the copying would be performed from the *current* directory, which might not be `source`. You should use `"%source%%%I"` to include the source directory name. I'd suggest you edit your question to clarify matters. Do you simply want to replace `target` with the last file, or append the last file to it, or is it the first file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, so let me try to rephrase it:

I think you want to find the Most Recently Modified file with a .CZI extension, and copy only that newest file to some target destination.

To list all .CZI files in all subdirectories, sorted by newest-file first:

```
(for /f %a in ('dir *.CZI /s /b') do @echo %~ta %~fa) | sort
```

If the first line of this output is the file that you want, then all you need to do is copy that one file to your target.

*(and please, take the time to write detailed and clear questions so we can provide good answers)*

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume just the last modified file time from newest file is wanted from all *.czi files in directory `C:\Temp` containing for example:

```
30.01.2017  08:13  First Listed.czi
28.01.2017  21:26  Oldest Image.czi
03.02.2017  17:13  Newest Image.czi
```

The batch code for this task could be:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\Temp\"
set "Target=%Source%List.txt"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%Source%*.czi" /A:-D /B /O:-D /T:W 2^>nul') do (
   echo File "%%I" last modified on %%~tI>>"%Target%"
   goto AfterLoop
)
:AfterLoop
```

The command **DIR** searches in for *.czi files in directory `C:\Temp` and outputs the list sorted by last modification time in reverse order from newest to oldest.

In case of no *.czi file could be found, command **DIR** would output an error message to handle **STDERR**. This output message is redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it whereby the redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be interpreted as redirection operator on execution of **DIR** command line and not already on parsing **FOR** command line.

`%%I` references the name of the file as output by **DIR** and `%%~tI` references the last modification date of the file. The help of command **FOR** output by running in a command prompt window `for /?` explains those modifiers.

The loop is exited after first output of the text redirected to the target file on which the line is appended if it is already existing because of using `>>` instead of just `>`.

For the example files list the following line is appended to `C:\Temp\List.txt`:

```
File "Newest Image.czi" last modified on 03.02.2017 17:13
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`

See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).